# 4 pin round connector identification

Tags: sensor, identification, connector

Does anybody recognize this connector? I’ve scoured the internet, but can’t find any connectors with this type of keyway. It is for a data acquisition system.

[image]

Comment: It is a kinda PLT connector.

Comment: Brand/model of data acquisition system and/or sensor would be useful.

Comment: From that single, out-of-focus picture? No way. Please post multiple pictures, in focus, multiple angles, of _both_ mates: this one and the one this one plugs into. Also, measure the diameter in mm and tell us.

Answer (score 4):

The connector is called PLT series stright plugging connector.

### PLT-94-R+P

[image]

Image source: [Taobao](https://world.taobao.com/item/599220321461.htm)